# SPARQL Subquery Graph Name

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso, sparqlwrapper

I have following SPARQL query that contains a sub-select. The data contains multiple graphs and I want to know what graph the values for `?b` and `?m` come from:

```
select ?b, ?m, ?g1
where {

 {
    select ?o1, ?o2, ?e 
     where{
      graph ?g{
       ?s <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_infector_pid> ?o1.
       ?s <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_infectee_pid> ?o2.
       ?s <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_iteration> '0'^^xsd:decimal.
       ?s <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_exposureday> ?e.
       ?s1 <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/contactnetwork_pid1> ?o1.
       ?s1 <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/contactnetwork_pid2> ?o2.
       ?s1 <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/contactnetwork_acttype1> '5'^^xsd:decimal.
       ?s1 <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/contactnetwork_acttype2> '5'^^xsd:decimal
    }
   }ORDER BY ASC(?e) LIMIT 1 
}

{

graph ?g1 {
?b <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/getInfectedBy> ?o1.
?m <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/getInfectedBy>* ?b.
   }

}

}
```

The second graph pattern contains a transitive property path and the query provides following correct result:

```
 b                                                        m                                                        g1 
 -----------------------------------------------------    -----------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------- 
 <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#446734805>    <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#446753456>    <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/dendrogram/replicate1/>
```

However, I want to see the intermediate nodes and count the path length from transitive relationship. If I remove `graph ?g1` from the query, then it shows the intermediate node information like following:

```
 b                                                      m
 ---------------------------------------------------    --------------------------------------------------- 
 http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#446718746    http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#446718746 
 http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#446734805    http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#446734805 
 http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#446734805    http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#446753456
```

The Purpose of the query is to figure out graph name for matching `?b` and `?m`. Hence, I want to use `graph ?g1`. Is it possible to show intermediate nodes by retaining the `graph` keyword? I am using Virtuoso.

Comment: Off-topic: It's illegal SPARQL syntax with the `,`. And for readability, I'd suggest to make it more compact by using TURTLE features, especially for the first sub-select.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not using `g` the first `GRAPH` statement is not necessary.  Note also that the second `GRAPH` statement only uses `?o1`, so the following query do what you want it to.  You may also want to check [SPARQL syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) in your select clause.

```
PREFIX ndssl: <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/>
SELECT ?b ?m ?g1
WHERE {
  {
    SELECT ?o1
    WHERE {
       ?s   ndssl:dendrogram_infector_pid  ?o1               .
       ?s   ndssl:dendrogram_infectee_pid  ?o2               .
       ?s   ndssl:dendrogram_iteration     '0'^^xsd:decimal  .
       ?s   ndssl:dendrogram_exposureday   ?e                .
       ?s1  ndssl:contactnetwork_pid1      ?o1               .
       ?s1  ndssl:contactnetwork_pid2      ?o2               .
       ?s1  ndssl:contactnetwork_acttype1  '5'^^xsd:decimal  .
       ?s1  ndssl:contactnetwork_acttype2  '5'^^xsd:decimal
    } ORDER BY ASC(?e) LIMIT 1 
  }
  GRAPH ?g1 {
    ?b  ndssl:getInfectedBy   ?o1  .
    ?m  ndssl:getInfectedBy*  ?b   .
  }
}
```

In the endpoint provided there isn't a match for `?b` or `?m`, regardless of whether a `GRAPH` statement is used or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to apply the lowest value of the "?e"  that's why I used "ORDER BY ASC(?e) LIMIT 1" in my query. However, you omitted it from your answer. If I use the "ORDER BY" clause then I have the same problem as mentioned in my question. You can test my data through following SPARQL endpoint: "http://taos.vbi.vt.edu:8890/sparql"

Comment: OK, I see what the sub-select is about, but the question remains a bit vague.

Comment: endpoint provides match for ?b and ?m. My question is if I use "GRAPH" keyword then SPARQL select statement doesn't provide intermediate node from transitivity. However, if I omit  the "GRAPH" keyword then it works fine. That means it provides intermediate node information. Why is it so? I need intermediate node information with "GRAPH" URI.

Comment: There is no match at the endpoint for an `?o1` binding that also matches the criteria in the `GRAPH` statement, where `?b ndssl:getInfectedBy ?o1.`  This is the point where the query is failing to find a match.  It has nothing to do with `GRAPH` itself.  If you simply take 'graph ?g1` out of the query, there are no matches for `?b` and `?m` because the aforementioned triple pattern does not find a match for `?o1`..

Comment: Are you looking at the right SPARQL endpoint? It working for me. I am getting the result for `?o1' and for both with graph and without graph command. I am getting the results that I mentioned in the question. If you want then I can send you the result URLs. BTW my SPARQL endpoint is    [link](http://taos.vbi.vt.edu:8890/sparql)